# How to list all Classes an Object extends in Java?

Tags: java, decorator

In Java, I'm using the decorator pattern.  Sometimes an `Object` gets many types as it can be decorated with many classes. How can i get all the different types of an Object?

```
abstract class: plate
concrete class: JapanesePlate, WesternPlate

abstract plateDecorator extends plate
concrete decorators: MeatPlateDecorator, TomatoPlateDecorator,
```

Sometimes, a `JapanesePlate` can be decorated with `MeatPlateDecorator` or  `TomatoPlateDecorator` or both.

I just want to know whether there is any way I can know this?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "an object gets many types as it can be decorated with many classes"? It would help if you'd give an example.

Comment: I am interested why do you need to do that? It is against OO philosophy for a base class to know its child classes

Comment: Actually, i'm not using it, its only for some testing purposes.

Comment: @JonSkeet, i added an example

Answer (score 2):

You cannot find all of the classes that form an arbitrary decoration hierarchy, because a decorator *has-a* instance of a decorated class, and does not form an *is-a* relationship.

For a concrete example from the JDK: [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) is a decorator for input streams. It is part of a class hierarchy that includes `FilterInputStream` and `InputStream`, but that tells you nothing about the class that it is *decorating*.

If you happen to know how `BufferedInputStream` is implemented, you could use reflection to examine the stream that it's decorating, but that doesn't help you in examining, say `BufferedOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getSuperClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29). If required, you can also use `getInterfaces`:

```
   Class objectClass = object.getClass();
   while (objectClass != null) {
     Class parent = objectClass.getSuperClass();
     Class [] implementedInterfaces = objectClass.getInterfaces()

     objectClass =  parent; // continue upward in the hierarchy.
   }
```

Comment: actually, this plate.getClass().getSuperclass() solves my problem to some extent but it returns only class plate.PlateDecorator, but i want it more specific such as whether meat decorator or tomato decorator or both

Answer (score 0):

If you control the class hierarchy, your best option is probably to introduce a decorator interface:

```
public interface Decorator<T> {
    T getDecoratedObject();
}
```

Now your decorator walk can check for the special `Decorator` interface and pry open the wrapped objects as well.

If you can't change the classes, you will probably have to rely on reflection hackery and heuristics.